# Can we get a memory leak even if the app is killed?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-leaks

I can not understand this statement from [Activity.onStop()](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html#Stop):

> When your activity receives a call to the onStop() method, it's no
>   longer visible and should release almost all resources that aren't
>   needed while the user is not using it. Once your activity is stopped,
>   the system might destroy the instance if it needs to recover system
>   memory. In extreme cases, the system might simply kill your app
>   process without calling the activity's final onDestroy() callback, so
>   it's important you use onStop() to release resources that might leak
>   memory.

Specifically this part:

> In extreme cases, the system might simply kill your app process
>   without calling the activity's final onDestroy() callback, so it's
>   important you use onStop() to release resources that might leak memory

If the process is killed how can we get a memory leak if we don’t have release code in `onStop`? On app kill all resources are cleaned right?

Answer (score 9):

> If the process is killed how can we get a memory leak if we don’t have release code in onStop?

You can't. The Android documentation gots issues, yo.

> On app kill all resources are cleaned right?

Well, your process is terminated, which eliminates your RAM and threads. What you need to do is arrange to clean up anything that *isn't* tied to your RAM and threads. For example, if the user has entered data into the app that you want to keep and have not persisted yet, `onStop()` is a candidate time to consider forking the thread to save that stuff to disk.

Comment: Yes I understand about saving things. I could not understand how can we get memory leaks as described in the doc

Comment: Android makes heavy use of communication between processes, and in theory, resources held in *other* processes *on behalf* of the dead one could fail to be released upon its death if those programs are not written well enough to handle its unexpected disappearance.  There have been rumors about issues with the camera for example.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I agree that this is potential problem. IMHO it does not fit the documentation's description, though, as the activity lifecycle material does not address other processes. I have made a slight edit to my answer, to lump in your IPC scenario with other things that you might need to address outside of your process. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

If process is killed. All associated memory content will be removed from the system so killing the process will not leak memory.