# Can native resources leak when onDestroy() isn't called?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, resource-leak

The docs for [`Activity#onDestroy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) say:

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.

If the process is killed, will all native resources held by the activity be released?  Or are there some types of native resources that could be leaked by the framework killing the process?

**Edit:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29923210/1953590) addresses memory leaks.  I'm also not concerned about things like temp files being left on disk.  I'm mainly worried about leaking file descriptors.  (And unknown unknowns that might be lurking...)

Answer (score 0):

If the process is killed, nothing is leaked in that process.

This documentation exists for times when someone might have an idea to spin up a thread in an to do work and expect that work to continue indefinitely.  This is an incorrect use of an activity.  Instead, a "sticky" Service should be used that restarts when killed by Android so it can pick up where it left off when it was killed.